# Setting an environmental variable in a docker-compose.yml file is the same as setting that variable in a .env file?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, traefik

I'm trying to set a specific environmental variable in my `docker-compose.yml` file. I don't think my `docker-compose up` is registering/reading it correctly.

```
  apigateway.web:
    image: traefik
    command: --api --docker # Enables the web UI and tells Traefik to listen to docker
    environment:
      - COMPOSE_CONVERT_WINDOWS_PATHS=1
    ports:
      - "80"   # The HTTP port
      - "8080" # The Web UI (enabled by --api)
    volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock # So that Traefik can listen to the Docker events
```

I know I could set it in a `.env` file. Isn't this basically the same thing? Of course, the `.env` file is like auto adding an `environment:` section to *all* of my services in my `docker-compose.yml` file ... vs ... just setting that variable for 1 service. But besides that, it's the same thing, right? an environmental variable is an environmental variable.

I'm asking this because when I add that single environmental variable to that service I don't believe it's getting 'picked up / read' because this error still occurs:

```
Recreating 3ae831a08eab_dockercompose17057127240787984866_apigateway.web_1 ... 
Recreating 3ae831a08eab_dockercompose17057127240787984866_apigateway.web_1 ... error
ERROR: for 3ae831a08eab_dockercompose17057127240787984866_apigateway.web_1  Cannot create container for service apigateway.web: b'Mount denied:\nThe source path "\\\\var\\\\run\\\\docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock"\nis not a valid Windows path'
ERROR: for apigateway.web  Cannot create container for service apigateway.web: b'Mount denied:\nThe source path "\\\\var\\\\run\\\\docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock"\nis not a valid Windows path'
Encountered errors while bringing up the project..
```

And this error seems to be [talked about in this GitHub issue](https://github.com/docker/for-win/issues/1829) -> with the answer being: add an environmental variable `COMPOSE_CONVERT_WINDOWS_PATHS=1`.

Notes:

- I'm on a windows machine.
- Docker is running as Linux containers.

So -- am I right or what I'm doing is totally wrong and I actually do need to create a `.env` file because of .

thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I believe you want to set COMPOSE_CONVERT_WINDOWS_PATHS=1 on your host machine so docker-compose knows to convert the windows-style to unix-style volume definitions.

`$Env:COMPOSE_CONVERT_WINDOWS_PATHS = "1" 
docker-compose up`

Comment: The problem i have with this, is that if another dev downloads my image, then they _still_ have to do some ceremony :( I _know_ I can do that. I also know I can do this via an `.env` file ... but to answer the question -> is there a difference? (currently right now I'm setting this env var via a `.env` file to get this to work on my localhost).